# Adding needed string to Split-Path

Tags: powershell

I want to pass file as argument to:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd $SqlQuery -InputFile $sqlPath
```

The file is located in different folder. `Parent Folder -> Different Folder -> Desired File`

I accessed the `Parent Folder` using:

```
$sqlPath = Split-Path -Parent $PSScriptRoot
```

How can I add the final part to `$sqlPath`? It's my frist script and I have no idea how to add `\DifferentFolder\DesiredFile.sql` (string?) to this variable.

Comment: The inverse of `Split-Path` is `Join-Path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string interpolation to do this:

`$sqlPath = "$(Split-Path $PSScriptRoot -Parent)\DifferentFolder\DesiredFile.sql"`

If you place variables in a double-quoted string, PowerShell will replace them for you at run-time.  Even more flexible is the ability to place executable code inside a string (as shown in my example), using a sub-expression `$(...)`.  However, be careful not to make the string unreadable with too much code.  In some cases it is better to split this into multiple steps:

```
$parentFolder = Split-Path $PSScriptRoot -Parent
$sqlPath = "$parentFolder\DifferentFolder\DesiredFile.sql"
```

Answer (score 1):

What your after is how to do 'string concatenation', basically adding two strings to form a longer one, PowerShell has a few methods, but `+` works.

You also said you want to update `$sqlpath`, so

```
   $sqlpath = $sqlpath + "\DifferentFolder\DesiredFile.sql"
```

Should work.